# number.toLocaleString() is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, currency-formatting

`number.toLocaleString()` is not working in `react-native`, can anyone suggest better way to format currency in react-native,
code goes here

```
formatMoney(number) {

        if(number===undefined||number===null)
        {
            return 0
        }
        else
        {
            var n=number.toString
            var obj={
                style:'currency',
                currency:'GBP'
            }
            'use strict'
           return n.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });
        }
      }
```

Comment: I answered your question below. I would appreciate an upvote and marking it as accepted or any other feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format). It has these features

1. Prefix, suffix and thousand separator.
2. Custom format pattern.
3. Masking.
4. Custom formatting handler.
5. Format number in an input or format as a simple text

Sample usage

```
<NumberFormat value={2456981} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
```

Output : $2,456,981

Comment: I am getting config  error after yarn add 'react-number-format',does it support 'react-native'

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) function, therefore you need to make sure that you are calling it on a number and not on a string. See example below:

```js
var n = 5555;
//var n=number.toString(); remove this line
var obj={
    style:'currency',
    currency:'GBP'
}

formatted = n.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });
console.log("formatted",formatted);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on android